# Compute euclidean distance with R

Tags: r

I have two data frames with coordinates and different lengths, I'm trying to compute euclidean distance from each point of first date frame (for example 2 points) to every point of second data frame (for example 4 points):

**Result:**

```
point[1] dist1, dist2, dist3, dist4

point[2] dist1, dist2, dist3, dist4
```

**This is my script:**

```
i=1
for (i in dim(coordinates)[1]) {
  result[i]<- 
  sqrt((coordinates[i,1] - reference[,1])^2 + 
  (coordinates[i,2] - reference[,2])^2 + 
  (coordinates[i,3] - reference[,3])^2)
}
```

But it only returns distances from last point (point[2])
How can I fix the scrip??, any help would be great

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make this mistake all the time. *dim* returns a single number, so you need to loop *i* from *1* through *dim*.

I changed your second line to loop through the sequence 1:dim(coordinates)[1].

```
i=1
for (i in 1:dim(coordinates)[1]) {
  result<- 
  sqrt((coordinates[i,1] - reference[,1])^2 + 
  (coordinates[i,2] - reference[,2])^2 + 
  (coordinates[i,3] - reference[,3])^2)
}
```

Now you just need to make sure your *result* vector has two slots. If it doesn't work, put this at the beginning.

```
 result <- rep(NA, 1:dim(coordinates)[1])
```

Comment: Jajajaja, thank, you, thank you so much Chris, I haven't seen it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I put result at first, the mistake was with 1:dim(coordinates)[1]. Thanks Chris you help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

One can take advantage of matrix algebra and calculate the distances without loops.

For two matrices A, B where the rows represent instances and the columns represent the coordinates (i.e., in 3 dimensions both matrices have 3 columns), the matrix of squared distances can be calculated as

d^2(A,B) = ||A-B||^2 = A^2 + B^2 - 2*A*B

This can be translated to R, e.g., as follows:

```
d <- sqrt(    matrix(diag(A %*% t(A)), nrow=dim(A)[1], ncol=dim(B)[1])
          + t(matrix(diag(B %*% t(B)), nrow=dim(B)[1], ncol=dim(A)[1]))
          - 2*A %*% t(B) )
```

The resulting distance matrix has a row for each instance in A and a column for each instance in B.